# SQL - GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table with Column - D and E. 
I want to get D, Distinct E in each D, Count of total number of entry for each D. How to write SQL for this ?

Data:

```
D | E
-----
1 | K
1 | K
1 | A
2 | S
2 | S
2 | S
2 | S
```

Desired o/p:

```
    D | E | Total_E_in_D
   ----------------------
    1 | K | 3
    1 | A | 3
    2 | S | 4
```

---

```
    SELECT D,E,Count(E in each D) 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY D,E.
```

Last column should give me the total number of entries for each D.

Comment: An employee can be in a department multiple times?  That seems unusual.  Can you edit the question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I guess @Kishor didn't frame the question well. Please provide more details. What do you mean by distinct emp? How can one dept have same employee twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific answer to the question is:

```
select dept, count(*) as numemployees, count(distinct emp) as numDistinctEmployees
from d1
group by dept;
```

This just seems quite unusual, because the it assumes that employees would be in the same department more than once.

EDIT:

Strange data format, but just use aggregation with analytic functions:

```
select dept, emp, sum(count(*)) over (partition by dept) as numEmployees
from d1
group by dept, emp;
```

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I am getting an error for this SQL. Is it in Oracle?  Demo:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e8cf/21

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. I am not able to understand SUM(count(*).. part, can you please explain. I have split the data like this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e8cf/29   but not able to figure out how is it working

Comment: `count(*)` is an aggregation function.  `sum() over (partition by dept)` is an analytic function.  The analytic function is adding together all the values of `count(*)` within a department.

Answer (score 1):

You can group on the department and the employee, and join in a query where you group on the department to count the employees:

```
select
  e.Dept,
  e.Emp
  d.EmpCount
from
  table e
  inner join (
    select
      Dept,
      count(distinct Emp) as EmpCount
    from
      table
    group by
      Dept
  ) d on d.Dept = e.Dept
group by
  e.Dept, e.Emp
```

You could also use a subquery to count the employees:

```
select
  e.Dept,
  e.Emp,
  (
    select
      count(distinct Emp)
    from
      table d
    where
      d.Dept = e.Dept
  ) as EmpCount
from
  table e
group by
  e.Dept, e.Emp
```

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @KishorKumar: The queries are the same, just use `D` instead of `Dept` and `E` instead of `Emp`.

Answer (score -1):

how's this?

```
select dept, emp, (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.dept = t1.dept) noEmps
from table t1
```